# How to determine why a piece of code produces an infinite loop?

Tags: c, binary-search

This is my binary search function. I can't seem to find the error but every time I try to run the code it gives me a segmentation fault 11. I feel like my mistake has to do with my last else if statement.

```
void binary(struct list *A[], char search[15], int start, int 
end) {

    if(start <= end) {

        int middle = (start + end)/2;

        if(strcmp(search, A[middle]->name) == 0){

            printf("found");
            exit(0);

        } else if (strcmp(search, A[middle]->name) > 0){

            int start = middle + 1;
            int end = end;
            binary(A, search, start, end);

        } else if (strcmp(search, A[middle]->name) < 0){

            int start = start;
            int end = middle - 1;
            binary(A, search, start, end);

        } else if (start == (end - 1)) {

            printf("%s was not found in the list", search);
            exit(0);

       }

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you ever supposed to reach that last else-if statement if it only gets called when strcmp returns a number that is not 0, less than 0, or greater than 0?

Comment: Is the list sorted in lexicographically ascending or descending order? Also, you might benefit from getting rid of the int end = end; and int start = start; statements. The last else if block is irrelevant, the "was not found" message should be outside of the scope of your outer if block.

Comment: start and end are indices so it shouldn't matter no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statements

```
int end = end;
int start = start;
```

do not make sense because the variables are initialized by themselves while they have indeterminate values.

There is no need to declare local variables end and start. Use the parameters.

This statement

```
    } else if (start == (end - 1)) {

        printf("%s was not found in the list", search);
        exit(0);

   }
```

also does not make sense because initially the variables `start` and `end` satisfy the condition of enclosing if statement

```
if(start <= end) {
```

And at last it does not make sense to use standard function `exit` instead of the return statement..

Comment: okay yah so now it works but if I input something thats not in the list it doesn't print out that the "%s was not found in the list"

Comment: @EthanItovitch The last if else statement must be placed outside the initial if statement and be its else statement.

Comment: ooohh I see got it to work now thanks a lot ur the man Vlad from Moscow

Answer (score 0):

First, as others already pointed out, the assignment like `int end = end` is asking for troubles. Do a simple test and print the `start` and `end` values at the beginning of the function to see what happens as your program works...

Next, you do not need recursion here! Shrinking the search area can be easily done in a simple loop:

```
void binary(struct list *A[], char search[15], int start, int end) {
    while(start <= end) {
        int middle = start + (end - start)/2;

        int cmpresult = strcmp(search, A[middle]->name);
        if (cmpresult > 0) {
            start = middle + 1;
        } else if (cmpresult < 0) {
            end = middle - 1;
        } else {             // cmpresult == 0
            printf("found at %d", middle);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("%s was not found in the list", search);
}
```

Finally, please note the `middle` calculation – adding `(start + end)` is a common step to do that, however it may lead to error if the array is too long; specifically, if the array length exceeds a half of the maximum value representable by `int` type.